# Notification on Suggested Edit approval

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, notifications, rejected-edits

Currently, when someone suggests an edit, they are unable to keep track of it without watching reputation levels or constantly refreshing the page.

What I would like is a notification, that shows up like the notification where someone has edited your question, that shows whether a suggested edit has been approved or rejected after the last vote is cast.

This way, the community can be notified when their edit has been rejected/approved, while focusing their efforts on another question/answer.

Comment: You can also check back on your edits from the ["suggestions" activity tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1406409/azulflame?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).