# Add global notifications for rejected edits (No, I don't mean the edit warning prompt)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications, rejected-edits

There is a clear desire for global notifications when an edit is rejected. While there is a warning for rejected edits, it's not the same thing.

I don't believe this is a duplicate of "[Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)". While that request did mention a notification as an option, it was marked as completed with a different implementation. This is a new request, asking for the notification.

---

Over the years have been multiple requests for notifications when an edit is rejected. To solve this issue, [a small edit warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor/137334#137334) was added if you had recently rejected edits. Despite this, the requests kept coming in.

- [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor) (Jan 29 '12)
- [Also show rejection vote reasons for accepted suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127136/also-show-rejection-vote-reasons-for-accepted-suggested-edits) (Mar 27 '12)
- [Can rejected edits show up in your notifications?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133867/can-rejected-edits-show-up-in-your-notifications) (May 28 '12)
- [Notify on suggested edit rejection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136580/notify-on-suggested-edit-rejection) (Jun 18 '12)
- [Notification when a suggested edit has been approved or rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152908/notification-when-a-suggested-edit-has-been-approved-or-rejected) (Oct 29 '12)
- [Notification on Suggested Edit approval](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153344/notification-on-suggested-edit-approval?noredirect=1&lq=1)  (Nov 1 '12)
- [Display status of suggested edits in StackExchange inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157514/display-status-of-suggested-edits-in-stackexchange-inbox?noredirect=1&lq=1) (Dec 4 '12)
- [Edit rejection should be clearly indicated for the first few occasions, with notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184670/edit-rejection-should-be-clearly-indicated-for-the-first-few-occasions-with-not) (Jun 17 '13)
- [Keep track of your rejected edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230987/keep-track-of-your-rejected-edits) (May 4 '14)
- [Notify users when an edit is rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262222/notify-users-when-an-edit-is-rejected) (Aug 6 '15)
- [Add notifications about accepted edit suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295228/need-notifications-on-edit-acceptance) (Apr 26 '17)

---

**Note that nearly all of these questions have been closed as duplicates, linking back to the [implemented warning for rejected edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137334/351462).**

I think there are quite a few valid reasons why some users would prefer global notifications to the current 'warning' system.

- Users already receive notifications for accepted edits via the +2 rep gain
- The current edit warning doesn't immediately specify *which* edits were rejected
- It's unclear whether the rejected edit warning is being shown for a recent rejection, or an old rejection you already knew about
- You only see the warning the next time you suggest an edit, which could be days or even weeks later
- The rejected edit warning is site-specific, meaning it doesn't display when visiting any of the **[nearly 170 other SE communities](https://stackexchange.com/sites)**.

Personally, I would love the option for rejected edit notifications. It would help me realize when a large amount of my edits have been rejected, and how I can improve my edits in the future. With this said, in remembrance of all the mislabeled duplicates before me cut down before their prime, I will ask the oft-repeated question.

**Can users receive notifications when one of their edits is rejected?**

---

If SE wants to avoid showing rejected edits to users by default, a good compromise would be an opt-in option for notifications in account settings.

Comment: Apologies for the wall of text. I've never been good at [catchy formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17363/351462). :P

Comment: I'm with this. Unless you use a notification, the "rejected" would keep posting rejectable edits, because they don't know what's wrong. I'm saying this from my experience on a quieter site even. Most people don't visit chat and I don't have superping powers, and unless I create noise by commenting under a post, they'd keep proposing bad edits.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate? It exactly describes "Feature Request #1" from the post you said it was not a duplicate of (although you did not describe how it was different).

Comment: @JasonC: I think this is being asked separately because the original question was effectively modified in implementation and isn't going to be finished out in its original form.

Comment: @NathanTuggy You said it better than I could have myself.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro I've retracted my vote and edited your post in an attempt to clarify. However, if you are going to say "this is not a duplicate", please have the courtesy to also say why so that we don't have to spend the time verifying.

Comment: I would also like to add that in my opinion, the current rejected edit warning is barely noticeable. I didn't even know it existed until I read about it on Meta. I don't have that many rejected edits, but enough that I would have noticed something better earlier. What most people probably think, including me, is that they've already read that yellow box (if they even ever read it) and there's no point in reading it again, so they don't notice that there is a warning that their last edit was rejected.

Answer (score 3):

I think this idea seems reasonable, and given the explanation I fully agree that this is not a dupe and enough time has passed that a new discussion about this idea is justified.

I have a few concerns, though. My major general concern is the possibility that this will unnecessarily increase the amount of meta complaints from users wondering why their edits were rejected, to no real end. I have no concrete evidence to back that up, it is only conjecture. Still, I am traumatized by the number of complaints that stem from negative feedback in general ("my post was downvoted", "my post was closed", etc.) and have similar concerns here. In general, there seems to be a policy of *not* giving notifications of negative events, and for good reason.

In any case, breaking down some of the points individually:

> - Users already receive notifications for accepted edits via the +2 rep gain

Tied in to some of the concerns mentioned above, the existence of a positive notification does not justify the existence of the corresponding negative one (in the same way that the existence of answer notifications is not a rationale for adding closure notifications).

(PS, fwiw, that +2 gain stops after you've gained 1000 points through edits, or you've obtained the edit privilege.)

> - The current edit warning doesn't immediately specify which edits were rejected

There is a link to the recent edits, where you can review. If multiple edits were rejected this gives an opportunity to look at all of them. Still, fully support the notion of making it clearer. Personally, I think a list of recently rejected edits directly in the warning could be useful. On the other hand, that *does* only save one click.

> - It's unclear whether the rejected edit warning is being shown for a recent rejection, or an old rejection you already knew about

This seems like a solid point. There is no way for the system to know if you already know about a rejected edit, and a notification would solve that.

On the other hand, I'm not sure if it necessarily *matters*. If you receive this warning, you need to become a better editor. If, when reviewing your list of recent edits, you happen to re-look at a rejected edit you already knew about, this doesn't really *hurt* anything aside from wasting a small amount of your time, but then again, if you start making better edits, you won't have to spend time reviewing rejected ones any more. This is a weak "on the other hand", though. I do think that if there are any compelling reasons to have a notification, your bullet point here plus your last point (below) would be those reasons.

> - You only see the warning the next time you suggest an edit, which could be days or even weeks later

This isn't so much a point for the notification as it is a point for *keeping the warning* (regardless of a notification). See, the purpose of the warning is to let you know that you need to improve your editing. On the extreme, if you never make another edit again then it doesn't matter. More generally, *it does not matter if you improve your edit skills until you actually make another edit*. You *want* to see an old warning right as you are about to make a new edit. This is the most important time to let you know you need improvement: When you're about to take an action.

If the choices are:

1. Rejected edit → warning → a few weeks pass → edit something, vs.
2. Rejected edit → a few weeks pass → warning → edit something

I'd rather users go through flow #2, so that their previous mistakes are fresh in their mind when they're about to potentially make another mistake, instead of giving them a long period of time to forget the feedback.

So if there were to be a notification, the warning really ought to stay as well.

> - The rejected edit warning is site-specific, meaning it doesn't display when visiting any of the nearly 100 other SE communities.

This is a great reason for a notification. To be honest I'd rather see the warning be global but I have a hunch that isn't exactly feasible to implement, and a notification would help out here.

I suppose you could make a counter argument here that editing policies may vary by site and so "global" is not appropriate, but I think that doesn't matter, since this is feedback on what *not* to do rather than on what you *should* do, and so any improvements to your editing skills in this regard will likely benefit you on every site.

---

That said there's a bit of a bigger picture thing to consider here which also keeps me on the fence: Does this *matter*?

I mean, what are the downsides to continuing to not have a notification? See:

- Users who are serious about their edits and motivated to contribute positive changes, or motivated to improve, won't have much issue reviewing their rejected edits on their own. And even if they don't take initiative and only react to warnings, the reasons for rejection are a small enough set that even if they miss a few of their rejected edits when reviewing their rejections, there's still quite a lot of opportunity to learn.
- Users who improve naturally on their own over time, well, all these warnings and notifications are moot for them.
- On the other hand, to be blunt, users who can't improve *without* the notification will either end up edit banned or just stop editing, *and this doesn't hurt us*. These people aren't contributing anything particularly critical to site quality.

---

So: **TL;DR**: Totally on the fence, but:

- Notification or not, the warning should also stay.
- Out of your points, the following two seem the most compelling, and the rest do not:

  - "It's unclear whether the rejected edit warning is being shown for a recent rejection, or an old rejection you already knew about."
  - "The rejected edit warning is site-specific, meaning it doesn't display when visiting any of the nearly 100 other SE communities."
- I still wonder if this matters in the grand scheme of things.
- The possibility (again, though, conjecture) of increased meta complaints about rejected edits kind of offsets what appears to be marginal gains. I could probably be convinced if a better argument about concrete positive end effects was given.

Comment: Very good analysis. A point I don't make in my post is the idea of making rejected edit notifications optional. If it were possible, I know I'd turn the feature on.